# After requesting user permissions, where do I retrieve the user's details?

Tags: facebook

I'm new to developing Facebook Applications. I've managed to create a Login button for my website which can retrieve Basic Information.

How do I retrieve that Basic Information later (i.e. Name, Gender)? Does Facebook store this for me (in some dashboard somewhere?), or will I have to retrieve those details and store it myself when the user accesses my Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its totally depend upon you. Facebook doesn't store such information for you. Its up to you that if you want to store that information in your databse and don't request each time to facebook. But You can send request to facebook each time to get the same information. Each time you will send the same request and retrieve the information same as you did. 
You can use [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/), [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for such operations

Comment: How do I send a request to Facebook? Do I have to do it at the point when the person is accessing my app? Or can I access it later? It seems like I need a token, and that token expires in 2 hours or something?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should store it on xml or in a database. Facebook only provides you what you asked for and doesn't store anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the information yourself via graph API.All that user did was allow your app to access his data, what to do with that data is up to you .Depending on what programming language you're using there are different libraries to make getting information easier.

Comment: Thanks, mate. So you're saying, since the user allowed access to my app, I can retrieve it as long as I have the access token? I won't be able to access it later if the user is not actively using my application, right?

Comment: You can access the information until token expires. It lasts for quite a while from my experience, but you should search documentation to find a way to see when token expires